# Installation problem during boot

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I have a HCL ME laptop with the following hardware specifications: Intel dual core T4200 @2.00GHz, 3GB RAM, Video Card: NVIDIA Geforce 8200M G, OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit.

When I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 through a CD/USB drive, it will boot from start menu and after the welcome screen, it only shows me a cursor and nothing else.

Please help me out. Is it possible to install Ubuntu in my laptop or not?

Answer (score -1):

First try refreshing your GUI by typing (CTRL+ALT+F7). If this doesn't work then try updating your computer from the TTY console. You can get to that by pressing (CTRL+ALT+F1). Login in with your username and password, then type

`sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`

This should fix any missing dependencies on your computer. When you are done, type

`sudo shutdown -r now`

to reboot your machine.

If any of this doesn't work, reinstall your LiveCD and reinstall Ubuntu.

Good Luck!

Comment: He didn't installed it yet